# strip_tags - безопасна ли функция?

Tags: php

Когда-то читал, что strip_tags (или функция с похожим названием) не безопасна. Правда ли?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На [страничке с мануалом](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) есть два замечания, одно из которых это:

> Из-за того, что **strip_tags()** не
> разбирает HTML синтаксически, незакрытые теги в
> строке могут привести к тому, что
> функция уберёт лишние куски текста.

Например:

```
echo strip_tags("<p>Trolole<p olole"); // "Trolole".
echo strip_tags("<p>Trolole<madtag olole"); // То же самое
```

Другое предупреждение заключается в том, что

> Эта функция не убирает никаких
> атрибутов разрешённых тегов (аргумент
> allowable_tags), включая style,
> onmouseover и т.д., что тоже может
> сотворить непредвиденный фейл.

Например:

```
echo strip_tags("<b onmouseover=\"alert('hack!')\">сайт взломан</b>", "<b>");
```

**PS:** см. комментарии.

Comment: Ну так можно о многих функциях говорить... И такого рода исключения (атрибуты и т.д.) должны ИМХО обрабатываться отдельно и опять таки это тоже очевидно... по поводу незакрытых тегов - это абсолютно нормально и логично...

Comment: Ну в `htmlspecialchars();` по сути нет никаких исключений. И на её страничке (что характерно) никаких предупреждений нет. Про неё так никак не скажешь, т.к. она безопасна - нельзя проколоться.

Comment: ну текст вида `<b><h1>текст<span>текст</span>></h1><b>` тоже не есть нормально какбы :)

Comment: Разумеется, ненормально, хотя смотря какую цель преследуешь - может это как раз для показа html делается. Но вопрос не в этом. Вопрос в безопасности.

Comment: Использование htmlspecialchars гарантировано не позволит навредить сайту. strip_tags - вроде как не предназначен для этого (для защиты), но прочитав описание к функции, человек может подумать, что она нужна для убирания html-тегов (это ведь делает html-код безопасным?) что сможет привести к незапланированному убиранию кусков текста. Плюс человек может разрешить теги типа <b>, <i> и т.д. Поэтому и предупреждают о том, что на самом деле эта функция не делает никакой защиты, хотя с первого взгляда (да и название только) можно подумать, что делает.

Comment: Ну надо понимать<br>
чтобы и ктобы не писал всеравно все надо тестить самому &copy;

Comment: Про это никогда нельзя забывать))

Comment: Ее еще мат-фильтры очень любят - не юзайте в них такую конструкцию)

    $text = 'это <b>на</b><s>е</s><span>бывает фильтр</span> =)';
    если нет_мата($text) то
      добавить_в_базу(strip_tags($text));

я прошу прощения, если пример слишком "живой" (._.)

Answer (score 0):

Cмотря что вы подразумеваете под "небезопасностью", если вы о том будет ли она нарезать теги - да, будет. Является ли она решением всех проблем безопасности и т.д. - нет...
Собственно а чем она может быть небезопасна то?

Comment: Значит я ошибся названием...